# Forth でループができない

Tags: forth, gforth

次の Forth プログラムを書きました：

```
\ ループを作る
: メイン 10 0 do i . ;
メイン
bye
```

`gforth helloworld.fs` でコードを実行すると、次のエラーメッセージが表示されます。

> helloworld.fs:2: unstructured 
>   : メイン 10 0 do i . >>>;<<<
>   Backtrace:
>   $7F3EB462E988 throw 
>   $7F3EB463E478 c(abort") 
>   $7F3EB464B4A0 def? 
>   $7F3EB4637858 ;-hook

私のコードは何が間違っていますか？

Answer (score 2):

Forth のループは `do ... loop` の形を[しています](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/6-forth-do-loops/)。最後に `loop` を入れてください。

```
: メイン 10 0 do i . loop ;
```